# $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0,1<r<3,0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0,1<r<3,0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$

$u(1,\theta)=u(3,\theta)=0,0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$

$u(r,0)=(r-1)(r-3),u(r,\frac{\pi}{2})=0,1\leq r\leq3$

I have no idea how to solve this pde, does anyone could help me?　Thanks very much!!